# Problem: Undefined variable $category in C:\xampp\htdocs\webbanhang\single-product.php on line 123

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
    function getSimilarProduct($id, $category){
        include('connect.php');
        $sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_category = '$category' and product_id != $id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
        $sql->execute();
        return $sql->get_result();
    }
```

```
<?php
$similar_product = getSimilarProduct($id, $category);
while($sim = $similar_product->fetch_assoc()){
?>
```

I had used the variable $category before in my code and it worked:

```
    function getProductByCategory($category) {
        include('connect.php');
        $sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_category = '$category' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
        $sql->execute();
        return $sql->get_result();
    }
```

I tried deleting the $category in:

```
$similar_product = getSimilarProduct($id, $category);
```

but showed the message Fatal error
: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function getSimilarProduct(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\webbanhang\single-product.php on line 123 and exactly 2 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\webbanhang\db\getdata.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\webbanhang\single-product.php(123): getSimilarProduct('15') #1 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\webbanhang\db\getdata.php
on line
31

I'm sorry if the question is unclear as I'm a student and not very fluent in English.

Comment: `I tried deleting the $category`...why? The function requires you to provide it. What are you trying to achieve by deleting it?

Comment: Btw.: Use prepared statements (correctly) when using SQL queries with variables, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php